# Return on asset value for one company different on Yahoo Finance and on Market watch

Tags: return, yahoofinance

I am wondering why the return on asset (ROA) is so much different for a company when reported on Yahoo finance and Market watch website.
Here is Yahoo finance link: [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IESC/key-statistics?p=IESC)
and here is Marketwatch link: [MarketWatch](http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/Stock/IESC/profile?CountryCode=US)
The ROA on Yahoo finance for IESC is 5.75% and on MarketWatch is 38.89%.

Why there is this huge difference?

I am wondering if there are other free online resources I can check ROA and see what majority report?

Comment: ROA is Net Income divided by Total Assets, so either the two sources disagree in their assessment of Net Income, or they differ in their assessment of Total Assets, or both. Since they have similar numbers for Net Profit Margin (16-17%) the difference is probably in their assessments of Total Assets. Unfortunately neither source reports what figure they are using for Total Assets, so we can't easily check.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor do you know of any other free online resource that reports ROA?